# Pagination in Isotope

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I am using SharePoint. In a web part I manage to add the Isotope behaviour for a set of items I retrieve through code. I referred [this link](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wfaGu) to get a feel on Isotope behaviour.

```
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
      return qsRegex ? $(this).text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    }
  });
```

Can I know whether pagination is available in Isotopes

Comment: Pagination is not built into isotope. Implementing pagination in Isotope creates difficulties with Isotope filtering and sorting. Would you like all the Isotope elements to be filterable and sortable from every page? Or would you like only the elements on the current page to be accessible for sorting? I think pagination would be possible but difficult with Isotope even though David Desandro has [stated](https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/724) that "Pagination + Filtering are conflicting mental models".

Comment: @TovlyDeutsch Thank you for the reply. It would be confusing to the users if pagination is there, and on filtering users get results which does not belong to the current page....So I would be happy to filter what is available in the current page only, not every thing. I am wondering if other JQuery plugins support the Isotopes model in achieving pagination.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but [here](http://tannermoushey.com/2012/12/isotope-paging/) is a link to a tutorial on implementing pagination with Isotope v1 and Wordpress. You could use the general concepts in the tutorial to implement pagination with SharePoint and Isotope v2.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen http://codepen.io/Igorxp5/pen/ojJLQE?

```
    $(document).ready( function() {

    var itemSelector = '.grid-item'; 

    var $container = $('#container').isotope({
        itemSelector: itemSelector,
        masonry: {
          columnWidth: itemSelector,
          isFitWidth: true
        }
    });

    //Ascending order
    var responsiveIsotope = [
        [480, 4],
        [720, 6]
    ];

    var itemsPerPageDefault = 10;
    var itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
    var currentNumberPages = 1;
    var currentPage = 1;
    var currentFilter = '*';
    var filterAtribute = 'data-filter';
    var pageAtribute = 'data-page';
    var pagerClass = 'isotope-pager';

    function changeFilter(selector) {
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
    }


    function goToPage(n) {
        currentPage = n;

        var selector = itemSelector;
            selector += ( currentFilter != '*' ) ? '['+filterAtribute+'="'+currentFilter+'"]' : '';
            selector += '['+pageAtribute+'="'+currentPage+'"]';

        changeFilter(selector);
    }

    function defineItemsPerPage() {
        var pages = itemsPerPageDefault;

        for( var i = 0; i < responsiveIsotope.length; i++ ) {
            if( $(window).width() <= responsiveIsotope[i][0] ) {
                pages = responsiveIsotope[i][1];
                break;
            }



        }

        return pages;
    }

    function setPagination() {

        var SettingsPagesOnItems = function(){

            var itemsLength = $container.children(itemSelector).length;

            var pages = Math.ceil(itemsLength / itemsPerPage);
            var item = 1;
            var page = 1;
            var selector = itemSelector;
                selector += ( currentFilter != '*' ) ? '['+filterAtribute+'="'+currentFilter+'"]' : '';

            $container.children(selector).each(function(){
                if( item > itemsPerPage ) {
                    page++;
                    item = 1;
                }
                $(this).attr(pageAtribute, page);
                item++;
            });

            currentNumberPages = page;

        }();

        var CreatePagers = function() {

            var $isotopePager = ( $('.'+pagerClass).length == 0 ) ? $('<div class="'+pagerClass+'"></div>') : $('.'+pagerClass);

            $isotopePager.html('');

            for( var i = 0; i < currentNumberPages; i++ ) {
                var $pager = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pager" '+pageAtribute+'="'+(i+1)+'"></a>');
                    $pager.html(i+1);

                    $pager.click(function(){
                        var page = $(this).eq(0).attr(pageAtribute);
                        goToPage(page);
                    });

                $pager.appendTo($isotopePager);
            }

            $container.after($isotopePager);

        }();

    }

    setPagination();
    goToPage(1);

    //Adicionando Event de Click para as categorias
    $('.filters a').click(function(){
        var filter = $(this).attr(filterAtribute);
        currentFilter = filter;

        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);


    });

    //Evento Responsivo
    $(window).resize(function(){
        itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: well, I will try in the near future to add comments to the code